# OpenCV detection with different colorspace

Tags: python, opencv, color-space

I am using opencv to detect objects with cascade classifiers trained on grayscale images and then testing detection on different color spaces (images initially color) and calculating precision/recall/harmonic mean.
im wondering why i get the same results for greyscale and rgb but different in other colorspaces?

```
      # Read the image
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)


    # convert to grayscale (default algorithm)
    if colorspace == "gray":
        colorCVT = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    elif colorspace == "hsv":
        colorCVT = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    elif colorspace == "hls":
        colorCVT = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
    elif colorspace == "lab":
        colorCVT = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    elif colorspace == "luv":
        colorCVT = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LUV)
    elif colorspace == "yuv":
        colorCVT = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
    elif colorCVT --"rgb"
        colorspace = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    else:
        colorCVT = image

    print('using color mode: '+colorspace)

    with open(outputFilename, 'a') as results:
        results.write("Running detection on image:  "+imagePath +"\n")
        results.write("Detecting using trained classifier: "+cascadePath +"\n")
    # results.close()


    # training PARAMS
    SCALE_FACTOR = 1.02
    MIN_NEIGHBORS = 5
    MIN_SIZE = (10,10)
    MAX_SIZE = (128,128)

    # Detect objects in the image
    objects = trainedCascade.detectMultiScale(
        colorCVT,
        scaleFactor=SCALE_FACTOR,
        minNeighbors=MIN_NEIGHBORS,
        minSize=MIN_SIZE,
        maxSize=MAX_SIZE,
        flags = cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )
```

Comment: i assume its because grayscale is implemented as just the avg of color channels but am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [API for detectMultiScale](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=detectmultiscale#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale), you will see that it expects the image to be grayscale. I assume that if it encounters a 3-channel image (be it BGR, HSV, or whatever), it tries to do a conversion to grayscale first.

Unfortunately, when presented with a 3-channel image, OpenCV has no way of knowing which colorspace that image is using since there is no metadata to indicate such a thing. This limitation is apparent even in the `cvtColor` call where you have to specify both the *source* and the destination colorspaces. So in the case of a 3-channel image argument to `detectMultiScale`, it appears to always guess RGB (or maybe BGR? your code on BGR2RGB seems buggy) as the colorspace, and of course that is only correct if that is actually the colorspace.

Comment: but i get different results with the other color spaces except rgb and gray are the same. if it had no way of knowing or it chose gray or rgb, the other space would give the same results as gray..
I wasnt sure about the BRG2RGB i threw that in to try to debug, i was iniitally giving it no param. and so - no param gives same as grayscale, but the others are diff....
(edited the code bug).

Comment: i also did a search and looked on the API page and cant find the reference to gray/grey but i might be overlooking it.

Comment: @jsky: to summarize, the only unambiguous way to pass the image into that function is to pass in grayscale. Passing in anything else is ambiguous (subject to undocumented assumptions made by the writer). It is a coincidence that both the API and your code tries to do the same thing: "if it is three-channeled, assume it is BGR, and then do a BGR to Gray conversion". This attempt will yield correct result if the input is truly BGR, and will yield wrong result otherwise. Suggestion: if you want to perform detection in different colorspaces, you can use `cv::split` to extract a single channel

Comment: it just occured to me that it might be that my result calculations might be wrong, so i added my full code.
it was one of the hypothesis of the experiment that maybe detection will be better or worse in diff color spaces, and i saw another example using it that way and i also saw that conversion function in the API, i guess i should've dived deeper into the docs. anyways its too late to change the experiment (or do more coding) now. i will just report the results as they are. thanks anyhow.

Comment: @jsky The docs specify that `image` should be of type `CV_8U`, which is single-channel, ie grayscale. The reason different color spaces yield different results is because the conversion to grayscale is wrong in different ways, depending on the true colorspace in each case.

Comment: @ScighSchagh 
what i understand is being said is that even though ive told openCV to convert to another colorspace, when i run detect it will convert it to grey scale. and given there are different implementations of this based on different color spaces, and that different greyscale algorithms can yield different results (Kanan 2012), what i was doing is a perfectly valid use case for me to investigate this?

Comment: @jsky, I don't think that's quite right. Let's look at concrete examples. The conversion from BGR to gray is `0.299*r + 0.587*g + 0.114*b`; the conversion from HSV to gray is simply to pull the `v` out of the triplet. So if the image is HSV, and the code assumes it is BGR, then instead of simply using the V, it "computes" the gray value as `0.229*v + 0.587*s + 0.114*h`. Clearly, the hue and the saturation should not be part of the gray-scale value, so you get something very wrong. For your other colorspaces, the linear combination of `0.229 0.587 0.114` will do other weird things.

Comment: i see what ur saying now. might be useful for the docs to make that abit clearer.

Comment: i also thought i should note, that the hypothesis to test detection in different color spaces is not invalid. opencv just doesn't support this in this manner, only in the `cv::split` manner described by @rwong above.